# libGDX json error

Tags: json, arraylist, libgdx, save

I want to save an Arraylist of Items and save and load it. 
This is how I want to load the Arraylist:

```
public static ArrayList<Item> inventory = new ArrayList<Item>();
 public mainscreen(final luckyllama gam) {
        game = gam;
        json = new Json();
        json.setIgnoreUnknownFields(true);
                 if(  json.fromJson(ArrayList.class,
                Gdx.files.internal("data/inventory.json")) != null){
                     ArrayList<JsonValue> list = json.fromJson(ArrayList.class,
                             Gdx.files.internal("data/inventory.json"));
                     for (JsonValue v : list) {
                         inventory.add(json.readValue(Item.class, v));
                     }
                 }
...
```

This is how I save the Arraylist:

```
mainscreen.json.toJson(mainscreen.inventory, Gdx.files.local("data/inventory.json"));
```

This is **a part** of the Item class:

```
public class Item {
    public float x, y, speedx, speedy;
    public Rectangle container, icontainer;
    public Sprite texture;
    public int Quality;
    static  int amount;
    static int spawned;
    public int itemtype;
    static Item item;
```

And this is the json file after I saved the file:

```
[{
    class: com.algrande.luckyllama.Item,
    y: 50,
    speedx: -2.5,
    container: {
        y: 50,
        width: 50,
        height: 30
    },
    texture: {
        texture: {
            glTarget: 3553,
            glHandle: 1,
            minFilter: Linear,
            magFilter: Linear,
            uWrap: ClampToEdge,
            vWrap: ClampToEdge,
            data: {
                class: com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FileTextureData,
                file: {
                    class: com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglFileHandle,
                    file: {
                        path: items\\items.png
                    },
                    type: Internal
                },
                width: 4096,
                height: 4096,
                format: RGBA8888,
                pixmap: null,
                useMipMaps: false,
                isPrepared: false
            }
        },
        u: 0.25,
        u2: 0.5,
        v2: 0.25,
        regionWidth: 1024,
        regionHeight: 1024,
        vertices: [0,
        0,
        -1.7014117E38,
        0.25,
        0.25,
        0,
        0,
        -1.7014117E38,
        0.25,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        -1.7014117E38,
        0.5,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        -1.7014117E38,
        0.5,
        0.25],
        width: 1024,
        height: 1024,
        originX: 512,
        originY: 512
    },
    Quality: 1,
    itemtype: 62
}]
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
  Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: data/inventory.json
        at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:694)
        at com.algrande.luckyllama.screens.mainscreen.<init>(mainscreen.java:78)
        at com.algrande.luckyllama.luckyllama.create(luckyllama.java:19)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:147)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)
    Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Class cannot be created (missing no-arg constructor): com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture
    Serialization trace:
    texture (com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite)
    texture (com.algrande.luckyllama.Item)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.newInstance(Json.java:1042)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:892)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readFields(Json.java:797)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:919)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readFields(Json.java:797)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:919)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:947)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:692)
        ... 4 more
    Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.reflect.ReflectionException: Could not instantiate instance of class: com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture
        at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.reflect.ClassReflection.newInstance(ClassReflection.java:70)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.newInstance(Json.java:1024)
        ... 11 more
    Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.reflect.ClassReflection.newInstance(ClassReflection.java:68)
        ... 12 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>()
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
        ... 13 more
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Json's automatic deserialization relies on empty constructors for instantiating each object. Json can only deserialize classes by using their empty constructor. Since Item references a Sprite, which references a Texture; and since Texture does not have any empty constructor, you cannot deserialize Item automatically.

So your options are to

1) Set the sprite reference null before saving. Then switch it back.

2) Remove the reference to a Sprite in your Item class. Instead, pass a TextureRegion into the Item's render method if it has one.

3) Use a custom Json serializer. You could assign a serializer to Sprite that doesn't read or write anything. For example do this before reading or writing with your Json instance:

```
json.setSerializer(Sprite.class, new ReadOnlySerializer<Sprite>() {
    public Sprite read (Json json, JsonValue jsonData, Class type) {
        return (Sprite)null;
    }
}
```

Then your Item class will need a sprite assigned to it after it's loaded, perhaps like this:

```
public class Item {
    //...
    private String spriteName;

    //...

    /**Call this on every Item immediately after it has been loaded from Json. */
    public void onLoadedFromJson (TextureAtlas atlas){
        texture = atlas.createSprite(spriteName);
        sprite.setPosition(x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now the json looks like this: [{
 class: com.algrande.luckyllama.Item,
 y: 50,
 speedx: -2.5,
 container: {
  y: 50,
  width: 50,
  height: 30
 },
 icontainer: {
  x: 0.5,
  y: 82,
  width: 33,
  height: 18
 },
 textures: ,
 Quality: 1,
 itemtype: 66
},
{
 class: com.algrande.luckyllama.Item,
 y: 50,
 speedx: -2.5,
 container: {
  y: 50,
  width: 50,
  height: 30
 },
 textures: ,
 texture: item6,
 Quality: 3,
 itemtype: 26
}]  But I still get an error at " textures: ," (which is a sprite) even if it's null. Now I removed the Sprite and set it directly at rendering from the spritenam

Comment: e. But I don't know if it is good for the performance. Is there a better way to fix it?

Comment: I don't know the ins and outs of your setup. Instantiating a sprite from an already-loaded texture atlas isn't particularly slow. The only thing faster would be to reuse existing Sprite instances that you are no longer using after you load the Json.

Comment: There is some debate about this, but in my opinion, LibGDX's Sprite class should not be used because it deeply mixes game state and rendering. My game objects carry data about their game state, and each has its own render method where a texture atlas is passed in, from which it can pull a TextureRegion for drawing. (On the other hand, Sprite is theoretically less CPU intensive to use.)

Comment: public Sprite getItemTexture(int textureType){
        switch(textureType){

            case 1:
                return item1;

            case 2:
                return item2;
... 
 batch.draw(getItemTexture(item.texture), ... So even on android this isn't slow ? And do I need to dispose the created Sprites? This is the error log if I keep the Sprite thing now: Error parsing JSON on line 1 near: th: 33, height: 18 }, textures: *ERROR*, Quality: 1, itemtype: 66 }, { class: com.algrande.luckyllama.I

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing to create the Json file that still references `textures` since all three of my suggestions results in the Json file not even mentioning it. Sprites do not need to be disposed, but the Texture backing the sprite does (only after no objects anywhere are using that texture any more).

Comment: Thank You! So I just need to dispose the texture `item1` and not the texture of the sprite I'm creating in the render method?

Comment: I don't know what `item1` is. Generally, all your Sprites should be sharing a single Texture instance, so you would not dispose of it until nothing is using it any more. You should not be creating Sprites in the render method, because they are fairly heavy objects. Assuming you are going with my option 2 above, you should pass in the much lighter-weight object TextureRegion and draw that instead. The TextureRegion can be reused by many items. A Sprite is a TextureRegion that also stores positional data in an array, which is redundant since your Item object already stores that information.

Comment: Okay Thank you! I changed it to : ` public TextureRegion getItemTextureRegion(int textureType){
 switch(textureType) {
   case 1:
  return item1;
  case 2:
 return item2;
  case 3:
 return item3;
  case 4:
 return item4;
 case 5:
 return item5;
 case 6:
    return item6;
  case 7:
  return item7;
case 8:
return item8;
case 9:
return item9;
case 10:
return item10;
 case 11:
return item11;  case 12:
return item12;
default:
return error;
}} ` and    batch.draw(getItemTextureRegion(item.texture),...  `item1` is a Sprite which is loaded on start: `item1 = textureAtlas.createSprite("item1");`